# Python h2o in windows: cannot initialize (TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable)

Tags: python, windows, initialization, h2o

I am trying to use python h2o in my company.

After using the command:

```
>import h2o
> h2o.init()
```

I got

```
h2o\connection.py:110: UserWarning: Proxy environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` with value `http://username:password@proxy.**.com:8080` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.
warnings.warn("Proxy environment variable `" + name + "` with value `" + value + "` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.")

h2o\connection.py:110: UserWarning: Proxy environment variable `HTTPS_PROXY` with value `https://username:password@proxy.**.com:8080` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.
warnings.warn("Proxy environment variable `" + name + "` with value `" + value + "` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.")


No instance found at ip and port: localhost:54321. Trying to start local jar...


JVM stdout: c:\users\zchen6\appdata\local\temp\tmpqwjtad\h2o_zchen6_started_from_python.out
JVM stderr: c:\users\zchen6\appdata\local\temp\tmpegwtrj\h2o_zchen6_started_from_python.err
Using ice_root: c:\users\zchen6\appdata\local\temp\tmpftvwrm

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "h2o\h2o.py", line 722, in init
 password=password,max_mem_size_GB=max_mem_size_GB,min_mem_size_GB=min_mem_size_GB,proxies=proxies,size=size)

  File "h2o\connection.py", line 133, in __init__
    cld = self._start_local_h2o_jar(max_mem_size, min_mem_size, enable_assertions, license, ice_root, jar_path, nthreads)

  File "h2o\connection.py", line 269, in _start_local_h2o_jar
    jver = subprocess.check_output([command, "-version"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
   process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
   errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 913, in _execute_child
   args = list2cmdline(args)

 File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\subprocess.py", line 616, in list2cmdline
  needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I tried to set the value to the variable named proxy in init(), it still gave me the same kind of error.

After trying

```
h2o.init(start_h2o=False)
```

I got

```
h2o\connection.py:110: UserWarning: Proxy environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` with value `http://username:password@proxy.**.com:8080` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.
  warnings.warn("Proxy environment variable `" + name + "` with value `" + value + "` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.")

h2o\connection.py:110: UserWarning: Proxy environment variable `HTTPS_PROXY` with value `https://username:password@proxy.**.com:8080` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.
  warnings.warn("Proxy environment variable `" + name + "` with value `" + value + "` found. This may interfere with your H2O Connection.")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "h2o\h2o.py", line 722, in init
    password=password,max_mem_size_GB=max_mem_size_GB,min_mem_size_GB=min_mem_size_GB,proxies=proxies,size=size)

  File "h2o\connection.py", line 123, in __init__
    if not start_h2o: raise ValueError("Cannot connect to H2O server. Please check that H2O is running at {}".format(H2OConnection.make_url("")))
ValueError: Cannot connect to H2O server. Please check that H2O is running at http://localhost:54321/3/
```

By the way, the h2o version I used is 3.8.2.5.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I tried to set the value to the variable named proxy in init(),...".  Can you show exactly what you typed?

Comment: I tried `h2o.init(proxy={'http':'http://myusername:mypassword@proxy_address:port' ,'https':'https://myusername:mypassword@proxy_address:port'})`. It gave me same error.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the proxy should fix the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by turning off the proxy? Do you mean uncheck the box for proxy server in IE? If this is the case, the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

1) running with command "python filename.py proxy=(default)" worked for me, as this makes h2o connection to use default environment proxy.

2) have deleted http_proxy in user variables which is existing in my environmental variables.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout if your firewall allows the connection with the h2o server. Maybe give it a try by disabling the firewall first